# Split Django ModelForm selection base on previous field

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

So Im making a booking form, I have my Booking Model :

```
class Bookings(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, verbose_name="کاربر",)
    booker_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, verbose_name="نام",)
    booked_time = models.ForeignKey(AvailableHours, on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='booked_time', verbose_name="سانس",)
    booking_code = models.IntegerField(unique=True,default=random_string, verbose_name="کدپیگیری",)
    confirmed = models.CharField(max_length=100,choices=BOOKING_STATUS,default='در انتظار',null=True, verbose_name="وضعیت",)
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "رزرو ها"
        verbose_name = "رزرو"
    def __str__(self):
        return f'{str(self.booker_name)} - {self.booked_time} ** {self.confirmed}'
```

and my booked_time is based on :

```
class AvailableHours(models.Model):
    free_date = models.ForeignKey(AvailableDates,verbose_name="تاریخ فعال", null=True, blank=True,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='freedate')
    free_hours_from = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True, verbose_name="از ساعت",)
    free_hours_to = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True, verbose_name="الی ساعت",)
    status = models.BooleanField(null=True,default=True, verbose_name="آزاد است؟",)
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "سانس ها"
        verbose_name = "سانس"
    def __str__(self):
        return f'{str(self.free_date)} - {self.free_hours_from} الی {self.free_hours_to}'


class AvailableDates(models.Model):
    free_date = jmodels.jDateField(null=True, verbose_name="تاریخ فعال",)
    status = models.BooleanField(choices=AVAILABLE_DATE_CHOICES,null=True,default=True, verbose_name="وضعیت",)
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "روزهای فعال"
        verbose_name = "روز فعال"
    def __str__(self):
        return f'{str(self.free_date)}'
```

I cannot workout how to split my Dates and Hours fields in ModelForm.

```
class BookingForm2(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Bookings
        exclude = ('user','booking_code','confirmed',) 

    def __init__(self,*args, **kwargs):
        super(BookingForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['booked_time'].queryset = AvailableHours.objects.filter(status=True)
```

so in frontend user picks from a dropdown menu the AvailableDates then picks AvailableHours made in that model.
Anyone can suggest a workaround ?

Comment: You may need to use ajax to asynchronously load the available hours based on the date selected if you want to do this without a page refresh. 
Is that something you are looking for?

Comment: @ArunT I don't care if the page refreshes. I'm looking for a Django implementation not js/ajax

Comment: In that case, you will need to implement it using two forms. 
First form accepts the available dates, after that the user has to click a button and load another url/view with the next form for available hours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this with a beautiful Django package called [django-smart-select](https://github.com/jazzband/django-smart-selects/tree/master)